# AVAudioPlayer object not stable in swift

Tags: swift, swift4, avaudioplayer

I have a global variable audioPlayer. Every time user click on "Buzz" button, it call this function:

```
static func playBuzz() {
    if audioPlayer == nil {
        let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "6", ofType: "wav")!
        let contentURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: url)
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: contentURL)
            audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
        } catch {
        }
    }
    print("play buzz ")
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

}

But when I call this, it play sound very randomly. Sometimes it play sound, sometimes it don't play sound. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: `AVAudioSession` you don't need to set every time, shift that code in appDelegate, i think no need of `DispatchQueue.global().async` remove that as well n try again

Comment: I removed AVAudioSession, and remove DispatchQueue.global().async, but it still not work stable

Comment: Don't remove `AVAudioSession`, just shift that code in appDelegate

Answer (score 0):

The answer is when audioPlaying is play, I call play it won't process. My audio player have 1 second duration. 
So to fix this, I put more lines:

```
if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { //Make sure to call play() after audioPlayer finish playing. 
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
            return 
        }
    }
```